# Folder Not Raising 404 Error In htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Simply, I am trying to make it so if a user goes to a folder, it will give a `404 Error`. Problem is, it does not seem to work!

Here is my file setup:

```
- postin
    - mail
         - yourmail.php
    - profiles
        - viewprofile.php
    - .htaccess
    - error.php
```

Then simply I am adding this to my .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^mail/ - [L,R=404]
ErrorDocument 404 error.php
```

I thought by adding this code that if a user typed in the URL `.../postin/mail/` that it would take the user to the 404 error.php page. That does not seem the be the case though, it will just bring up the directory page for `.../postin/mail/`. So my question is, how do I raise the 404 error when a user goes to a folder (directory)?

---

If you would like my full .htaccess it is here:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

# skip all files and directories from rewrite rules below
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule search/(.+)/?$ search.php?query=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule search/?$ search.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule register/?$ registerpage.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule login/?$ loginpage.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule home/?$ home.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule users/?$ users.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule error/?$ error.php [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^mail/ - [L,R=404]
ErrorDocument 400 http://localhost/postin/error
ErrorDocument 401 http://localhost/postin/error
ErrorDocument 403 http://localhost/postin/error
ErrorDocument 404 http://localhost/postin/error
ErrorDocument 500 http://localhost/postin/error
ErrorDocument 502 http://localhost/postin/error
ErrorDocument 504 http://localhost/postin/error

<Files .htaccess>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use :

```
DirectoryIndex /errorpage.php
```

This should be the ver first line in your htaccess

Comment: What would this do? :) Please explain

Comment: This returns the error page when a directory is requested.

Comment: Ok, I will test it, and to verify it, before or after the `Options +FollowSymLinks` and `RewriteEngine on`?

Comment: You can place it anywhere before the "RewriteEngine On" line

Comment: Hmm, yea every time the `error.php` is called now, it is just raising `error 200` which is nothing. Do you know how to make it so it calles `error 403`?